# Pandas- DateTime Conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column that includes data in the following format: 05.01.2022. The dtype is object unfortunately and I need to convert that to datetime.

I tried the following:

```
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

The output is: ValueError: time data 'test' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y' (match)

Note I did not have any data or column named as 'test'.

I also tried a solution with astype('datetime') again did not work. How may I solve that problem? I checked the solutions in the similar posts but they did not work.

Thank you,

Comment: There seems to be an entry "test" in you datetime column. You can parse with `errors="coerce"` kwarg set in pd.to_datetime. That will give `NaT` for such entries

Comment: Hi sorry yes I found that, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your code is correct.

I tried it in the following environment:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

txt = '''date,amount
05.01.2022,133.15
06.01.2022,222.09'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt))
```

Now when you run `df.info()`, you should get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   date    2 non-null      object 
 1   amount  2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

Now your code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

(runs without any error).

The content of *df* is now:

```
        date  amount
0 2022-01-05  133.15
1 2022-01-06  222.09
```

Note a change in the format of the dates. This is the way *Pandas* prints dates with time part set to 0.

When you run `df.info()` again, you should get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   date    2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   amount  2 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes
```

Note that the type od *date* column is now *datetime64[ns]*.

To sum up:

1. First run my code to create the DataFrame.
2. Run `df.info()` and check whether the results match what I put.
3. Run your code on my data and check the result.
4. Create *df* your way (using your actual data).
5. Run `df.info()` (on your DataFrame) and look for any differences.
6. Check your DataFrame whether all rows in *data* column contain properly
   formatted dates.
   Look especially for cases when instead of the dot you have any other char
   (e.g. a comma).
   Look also for empty entries or leading spaces in *data* column.

Probably your DataFrame contains some other content from what you posted.